# Intro Page in ionic 2 Build Error

Tags: build, ionic2, declaration

My code is working correctly in browser but when I build using command

`ionic cordova build android --release --prod`
then it gives me this error

```
'Error: Type IntroPage in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/pages/intro/intro.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/app/app.module.ts and IntroPageMod in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/pages/intro/intro.module.ts! Please consider moving IntroPage in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/pages/intro/intro.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/app/app.module.ts and IntroPageModule in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/pages/intro/intro.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IntroPage in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/pages/intro/intro.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/app/app.module.ts and IntroPageModule in D:/Ionic Work/xxx/src/page/intro/intro.module.ts.'
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { IntroPage } from '../pages/intro/intro';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IntroPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    IntroPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Intro.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IntroPage } from './intro';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IntroPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(IntroPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    IntroPage
  ]
})
export class IntroPageModule {}
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { IntroPage } from '../pages/intro/intro';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  loader: any;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public storage: Storage, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    console.log("Here");
    this.presentLoading();

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.storage.get('introshown').then((result) => {
        if(result){
            console.log("in if");
            this.rootPage = HomePage;
        }  else{
            console.log("in else");
            this.rootPage = IntroPage;
            this.storage.set('introshown',true);
        }
        this.loader.dismiss();

      });
    });
  }

  presentLoading() {
      this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: "Authenticating .... "
      });
      this.loader.present();
  }
}
```

now in **App.module.ts** if I not Keeping **IntroPage** **in declarations and in entryComponents** then at run time it gives me Error that **No NG Module for IntroPage** , but this gives me output **build Successfully** (but app just show blank page ) and if I am Keeping That **IntroPage** then My code is executing in **browser correctly** but the **Build Gives me error** which I Mentioned Above

Answer (score 0):

If you included IntroPage in IntroPage module, you are implementing lazy loading of the page.

You should not import or include in **App.module.ts**. You also should not import *in any other page*.

In **App.component.ts**, remove the import of the page and use the string literal equivalent while pushing the page.

e.g:

```
        this.rootPage = 'IntroPage';
```

Also your Intro page should have a decorator

```
@IonicPage()
```

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

More on lazy loading [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit).